# Color confusion

Tags: color

I thought I know what a color is. And that there are color models, which you can convert colors between. But now, I am very confused:

In the corporate design of some company, I find this color: CMYK 100/54/4/19, RGB 0/82/147. I assume the former is 0..100, the latter 0..255.

At least for color calculators I find on the internet, they seem to differ, because [this one](https://www.farbtabelle.at/farben-umrechnen/) calculates that CMYK 100/54/4/19 = RGB 0/95/198.

To my further confusion, this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1.00,0.54,0.04,0.19}
    \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
    \color{white}
    
    \extractcolorspecs{titlepagecolor}{\model}{\mycolor}
    
    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{RGB}\tmp\tmp
\end{document}
```

tells me that xcolor converts CMYK 100/54/4/19 to RGB 0/69/196.

HOWEVER, changing the code above to RGB model and the color code from the style guide

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\selectcolormodel{RGB}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{titlepagecolor}{RGB}{0,82,147}
    \pagecolor{titlepagecolor}
    \color{white}
    
    \extractcolorspecs{titlepagecolor}{\model}{\mycolor}
    
    \convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{RGB}\tmp\tmp
\end{document}
```

gives me a visually appealing result.

Now I am confused. Can someone bring light into the dark?

Edit: Ulrike's example, in two viewers:

[image]

Comment: if it is 0-100? (but anyway converting between color models is a black art:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I extended the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

color conversion is not an exact science. It depends a lot where you view the color.

The following examples uses both color models in the same PDF:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn\sys_ensure_backend:\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
    \definecolor{titlepagecolorRGB}{RGB}{0,82,147}
    \definecolor{titlepagecolorCMYK}{cmyk}{1.00,0.54,0.04,0.19}
    \color{titlepagecolorRGB} \rule{4cm}{4cm}    
    \color{titlepagecolorCMYK} \rule{4cm}{4cm}
\end{document}
```

This shows in the stream (with adobe reader)

```
0 0.32158 0.57648 rg 0 0.32158 0.57648 RG  %<--- RGB
q
1 0 0 1 133.768 553.812 cm
0 0 113.386 113.386 re f
Q
1 0.54 0.04 0.19 k 1 0.54 0.04 0.19 K %<---- CMYK
q
1 0 0 1 250.475 553.812 cm
0 0 113.386 113.386 re f
Q
```

On my screen this gives:

[image]

The same with 0/95/198 as RGB gives this (if xcolor does the conversion the result is similar):

[image]

So imho whoever choose your values made a quite good job.

Comment: …I guess is why you should pay someone to work out your style guide. Thank you. I somehow thought there is a single formula to convert between those two color models (where they overlap), and that color models and stuff just is a matter of screen, pigments and paper. I did not assume that the problems already start earlier. What do I learn from this? Use the indended color model from the very beginning, and don't rely on automatic color conversion.